# mysql group_concat with ignoring empty string column

Tags: mysql, sql

MYSQL group_concat() function by default ignore null columns but it didn't ignore empty string columns. I have a field which is mediumtext type and not null. When I am using group_concat function on that the query generated unwanted ',,,' this type of value. How can i avoid this? 
Thanks in advance for your valuable time.

Answer (score 18):

Transfer empty string to null:

```
NULLIF(column1,'')
```

- **[NULLIF(expr1,expr2)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_nullif)**:
- Return NULL if expr1 = expr2

Comment: This is definitely nicer than using `IF( column1='', null, column1 )`.

Comment: What if we want do group_concat(distinct(column_name))? The above answer doesn't comply.

Answer (score 12):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT` with `IF(expr1,expr2,expr3)`, assume that you want concat `column1`:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(column1='', null, column1))
```

Comment: What if we want do group_concat(distinct(column_name))? The above answer doesn't comply.